# What is a technical sounding word to fill in " Bob ______ a certain path " ? It is something that means "followed", or "took" or "travelled"

Tags: word-request

It is used mostly in science or maths problems to convey for example, that Bob took a certain path to go from point A to point B. The word mainly describes the "travelling' along this path and not specifically the action of choosing one path among many.

Comment: Yes, THANK YOU, SO MUCH. Traversed is the word i was looking for. The context was exactly as mentioned. Bob traverses a path from A to B, Alice traverses a different path from A to B

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by G Warner, *to traverse* may fit:

> 1 a : to go or travel across or over
> b : to move or pass along or through

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/traverse))

Some scientific contexts in which it's used:

- It's mentioned a few times in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg#Euler%27s_analysis) about the famous graph theory problem "Seven Bridges of Königsberg", though mathematicians usually speak about *visiting* the edge of a graph rather than *traversing* it.
- You can [traverse a path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) in computer science.
- In physics, [traversable wormholes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole#Traversable_wormholes) may or may not exist.